# App Store: submitting app with future release date then changing it to earlier date after it is approved

Tags: app-store, release, appstore-approval

Lets say I submit my app for approval now. I set Availability Date to something like Nov. 30, 2011, because I have not yet decided when I really want to release my app. Then fortunately, my app gets approved.

1. Will I be able to edit the Availability Date after my app is approved?
2. Assuming question 1 gets a yes, let's say I then edit the Availability Date to Dec. 3, 2010. Will my app be available on the App Store on Dec. 3, 2010? I've heard that setting it to a future date after it was already available will take it out of the store, I want to know if the reverse also works.
3. Will there be any drawbacks for doing this? (This is actually my main concern)

For the record, I did search for similar questions, but still not satisfied with the replies in the other posts. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please share your experiences? Let's say that I submit an app today (on April 15, 2012), with a release date one month from now (on May 15, 2012). I have two specific questions: 1) Because I set the release date one month from now, does this mean that Apple will review my app later than it otherwise would have done? 2) Were you able to push your release date back after the app was approved? Thanks.

Comment: 1. I haven't seen any info on the web if Apple actually uses the release date for review prioritization, so I can't tell. 2. The app ended up getting approved later than our specified release date, so I didn't get to try it out.

Comment: I can confirm that you can set a release date for far in the future, then once approved move it back to the current day (or 1 day previous) when you are ready to go live. It took an hour or two after updating to appear in the app store (direct links only), and then another hour or so for it to show up in app store searches.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/559745).

Comment: Uh, ok, sure. I mean, it is a 7 year old question so... Do as you please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Yes, you can change availability anytime.
2. (and 3.) If you start selling your app by "accident" on a date that is today or before and then revoke it and then start  selling it again at later date you can have some problems. 
   The problem will be with all the sites that scans for new apps and then present them on the promo-sites. A lot of people will look at the promos and them when searching for the app it will be gone from App Store (since you temporarily revoked it). 
   At the later date when you WANT to release the app the promo-sites will see it as an old app and not promote it, and you will get fewer customers.

Comment: So can you confirm that I can actually set it to a far date then pull the date back and I will get on the app store on the date I pulled back to? Your answer for 2. (and 3.) is actually for selling it immediately then pushing the date forward, not setting it late then pulling the date back.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the availability date of your app in the "**Rights and pricing**" in the Manage Your Application part of the iTunesConnect site. This can be done at anytime in the publishing process.

Answer (score 0):

You may remove your app from all territories if you want to take it off of the store once is it in the store.  Then reenable the territory once you are ready for it to be for sale.  I think that is a better solution than mucking with the release date.

Comment: Even though this is Apple's own official instruction for temporarily removing an app from sale, there is a caveat: IF you are removing the current app from sale (perhaps due to an issue with that version) and submit a hotfix version to be reviewed, the updated binary WILL BE REJECTED if there are no countries ticked in Rights & Pricing, due to "Incomplete Metadata".