# Why can't I change an iPhone app release date?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, app-store, itunes

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420645/iphone-app-release-date-option-in-itunes-connect) states:

> You can only use the Version Release Control on app updates. It is not available for the first version of your app since you already have the ability to control when your first version goes live, using the Availability Date setting within Rights and Pricing.

However what I'm trying to do is change the availability date before it has been released.  My app was approved today and I'm trying to change the release date to Monday from Sunday.  Is there any way to do this?  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313308/app-store-submitting-app-with-future-release-date-then-changing-it-to-earlier-da) states that I can change my availability date but it's not clear how.

Anybody have any ideas on how to change the availability date within iTunes Connect?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using the App Store.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can do that in "Rights and Pricing".

Answer (score 10):

You never used to be able to change the release date. That was altered sometime earlier this year (Meaning that the first answer you found was right at the time of writing).

You can now change your release date by going to Rights and Pricing for your app and setting the date to be today (or a date in the past). It should change to 'Ready For Sale' and should be visible on the app store pretty soon (I assume the delay is for the change to propagate to all servers).

[image: Screenshot]