# iOS App Availability Date set far in future - how to release immediately now that it's ready?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

For a brand new iOS app, with the following pre-conditions:

- Availability Date is far in the future
- App is approved and Ready For Sale

How can one **immediately** (not even wait for midnight) release the app on-demand without waiting for a future availability date?

Comment: Can you not change the date in `Rights and Pricing`?

Comment: Yes you can, what date would I change it to, yesterday?

Comment: I would. It will still a little time to "process". Worth a shot though. Perhaps somebody else can provide some solid evidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a few articles relating to this.

> Use iTunes Connect to set a date when the app is available on the
>   store. For example, you can choose a date that immediately releases
>   the app to the store after it’s approved, or you can set a later date.
>   Using a later availability date allows you to arrange other marketing
>   activities around the launch of your app.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UsingiTunesConnect/UsingiTunesConnect.html

> You can change your app’s availability at any time, removing it from
>   sale or replacing it in the store. If you move your app’s availability
>   to a time in the future, your app is removed from the store until the
>   new date. It may take up to 24 hours to refresh your app’s
>   availability in stores in all territories.
>
> Before an app is approved, you may want to set the app’s availability
>   date to an arbitrary date in the future. When the app is approved by
>   Apple, you can decide more precisely when you want the app to appear
>   on the store.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html

To me the first statement suggests that if you set the release date in the past it will "immediately" release the app. - I found a similar post also stating the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7352542/2982796

What I have found it still takes 10 minutes for the application to show up on the direct link, then anywhere up to 24 hours to be searchable from within the app store.

Comment: Confirmed, setting date to yesterday makes the app appear near-instantly (there was about a 10 minute delay)

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience, I always set the release date to the date that I submitted it to the app store. This way as soon as its processed its released for sale. If the app is already approved and you had it originally set for a future date. Take the current date and time. It should release within a few minutes.